# NOT condition in regex

Tags: regex

I'm working with gsm modem and I want to parse command responses. I'd like to implement it with regex. So I have text below:

```
1.AT+CMGF=0
2.
3.OK
4.AT+CMGF=1
5.
6.OK
7.AT+ji
8.
9.ERROR
10.AT+CPMS="ME","ME","ME"
11.
12.+CPMS: 50,100,50,100,50,100
13.
14.OK
15.AT+CMGL="ALL"
16.
17.+CMGL: 0,"REC READ","+7914xxxxxxx",,"12/11/27,12:27:00+44"
18.04DEC0777E03001281 1892
19.+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","+7924xxxxxxx",,"12/11/27,12:33:51+44"
20.04DEC0742E00200176 646411 17983
21.+CMGL: 6,"REC READ","+7924xxxxxxx",,"12/11/27,13:28:00+44"
22.ERROR 
23.+CMGL: 7,"REC READ","+79098088xxx",,"12/11/27,12:40:16+44"
24.OK
25.
26.+CMGL: 49,"REC READ","+7924xxxxxxx",,"12/11/27,14:01:01+44"
27.010104480150014300 127051 0020640
28.
29.OK
```

I need to catch `ERROR` and `OK` after each operation and exclude them from messages in case if someone send them. I've tried next:

```
(\r\n)(OK|ERROR)|^("\r\n(OK|ERROR))
```

But it doesn't work. In another words I need to exclude lines #22, #24 and get the rest `OK` and `ERROR` lines.
Please, help.

Comment: There should be a string comparison or something like that in your language? If you read line by line, you should be able to filter those messages out?

Comment: Given the text above, what would be your expected output?

Comment: I must read whole text at once!

Comment: I would be splitting the payload by `\r` or `\n` and parse line-by-line. Regex isn't going to supplement ample parsing.

Comment: How do lines 22 and 24 differ from lines 6 and 9, for example?

Comment: The difference between these lines is #22,#24 are text inside SMS. #6,#9 are a responce to the commands!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit difficult to understand. If all you need is to remove the OK and ERROR messages from the string, a simple String.Replace() function should do. But if you want to grab the newline and return characters as well, you could use the following regex and replace with an empty string.

```
\r\n(?:OK|ERROR)
```

But this will replace all the OK and ERROR messages and not just the ones on lines 22 and 24.

I'm assuming that the line numbers are there only for presentation purposes and not part of the actual string you are trying to clean. If they are part of the string, the regex would need to be this:

```
\r\n\d+\.(?:OK|ERROR)
```